Any idea how can I get rid of the code appearing when I try to edit a page with Elementor?
I am using The7 theme on WordPress and every time I try to edit a post or a page with Elementor I have these pieces of code all over the page.
Any idea how can I get rid of it and edit the page normally?

Here's another example:

